# DBCC CHECKDB fails after restore to SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, backup, migration, sql-server-2017, dbcc-checkdb

I have a DB on SQL Server 2014 and after I restore a backup on SQL Server 2017 I get integrity check errors when running CHECKDB. When I restore it on another machine with SQL Server 2014 it works without CHECKDB reporting errors. I need to migrate the database to newer servers, so I can still update things as I see fit.

CHECKDB errors:

```
Msg 8948, Level 16, State 6, Line 5
Database error: Page (1:1737) is marked with the wrong type in PFS page (1:1). PFS status 0x40 expected 0x60.
Msg 8948, Level 16, State 6, Line 5
Database error: Page (1:1738) is marked with the wrong type in PFS page (1:1). PFS status 0x40 expected 0x60.
Msg 8948, Level 16, State 6, Line 5
Database error: Page (1:1739) is marked with the wrong type in PFS page (1:1). PFS status 0x40 expected 0x60.
Msg 8948, Level 16, State 6, Line 5
Database error: Page (1:1740) is marked with the wrong type in PFS page (1:1). PFS status 0x40 expected 0x60.
Msg 8948, Level 16, State 6, Line 5
Database error: Page (1:1741) is marked with the wrong type in PFS page (1:1). PFS status 0x40 expected 0x60.
Msg 8948, Level 16, State 6, Line 5
Database error: Page (1:1742) is marked with the wrong type in PFS page (1:1). PFS status 0x40 expected 0x60.
Msg 8948, Level 16, State 6, Line 5
Database error: Page (1:1743) is marked with the wrong type in PFS page (1:1). PFS status 0x40 expected 0x60.
CHECKDB found 7 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
CHECKDB found 7 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'DBNAME'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (DBNAME).
```

[image: Table view of errors]

Comment: Have you completed the CHECKDB on 2014, performed a new backup and then attempt the restore on 2017?

Comment: So, wait, the restore fails because of the errors, or the restore works but then checkdb *after* restore returns these errors?

Comment: post indicates restore fails because of the errors, not 100% clear. OP mentions "try" to restore, so I assume restore fails.

Comment: Yes I did a backup on 2014 which is without erros, and when I moved it to other servers it shows errors only on server 2017. Did CHECKDB changed between versions? Maybe the error is even in 2014 but it is not showing.

Comment: Restore works on 2014 and 2017 but CHECKDB does not pass only on 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out what object(s) those pages belong to by running:

```
SELECT s.name, o.name, a.index_id
FROM sys.schemas AS s
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
ON s.[schema_id] = o.[schema_id]
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations
  (DB_ID(N'DBNAME'),o.[object_id],NULL,NULL,N'LIMITED') AS a
WHERE allocated_page_page_id BETWEEN 1737 AND 1743;
```

You can try rebuilding that index (or table if index_id is 0 or null) to see if that fixes the allocation problem. If it remains, you could try dropping the index and re-creating it or, again, if it is a table or heap, selecting everything into a new table, creating the new indexes there, dropping the old table, and renaming the new one.

If that doesn't help, you can inspect the contents of those pages, and determine if it is acceptable to lose the data as a part of your upgrade (or, if not, to not upgrade).

```
DBCC TRACEON(3604,-1);
DBCC PAGE(N'DBNAME', 1, 1737, 2);
DBCC PAGE(N'DBNAME', 1, 1738, 2);
DBCC PAGE(N'DBNAME', 1, 1739, 2);
...
```

If it is an acceptable loss then you can run the repair with allow data loss as suggested (it might be smart to keep a copy of the backup before repairing in case you ever need to pull the data from those pages in some way).

Comment: I added an image of table view results. My object id is 0, so I cannot relate it to any table/index..

Comment: @user3790083 You read the whole answer, right? What do you see on those pages using `DBCC PAGE`?

Comment: Everything is zero. Looks like there is no data there. I just tried to use repair_with_data_loss and it repaired it in 2 cycles. I used data compare and there are no diffs. So I believe it is safe to use repair?

Comment: @user3790083 Seems fine, yes.